# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Silent notifications not working in background (iOS)

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm, cordova-ios

I'm using [FCM cordova plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase) to send Push Notifications to iOS device. When the app is in foreground, the app is able to receive all notifications. But when the app is in background (not killed), below is the behaviour

1. Notification appears in the Notification Center
2. Sometimes notification **data** does not reflect in the app when the app is resumed (from background to foreground). In a few cases, it does reflect in the app
3. Sometimes notification **data** does not reflect instantly. It take few seconds to reflect
4. Silent notifications (notifications that do not contain a message title and body, but just data) also do not reflect in app when the app is in background. Below is the payload for silent notification

   {
      "to":"token",
      "content_available":true,
      "notification":{
         "title":"",
         "body":"",
         "additionalData":"xxx",
         "sound":"default",
         "priority":"high",
         "content_available":"true"
      },
      "data":{
         "title":"",
         "body":"",
         "additionalData":"xxx",
         "sound":"default",
         "priority":"high",
         "content_available":"true"
      }
   }

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this? If so, what was the solution?